# read data from database using IOptionsSnapshot

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

in .net 6 API project, if im right IOptionsSnapshot is used to read data from appsettings.json file, apart from that my configurations are in SqlDatabase so, Is it possible to get those config data from Sql db using IOptionsSnapshot?

Comment: IOptionsSnapshot reads data from Configuration(appsettings.json is just one source of configuration). you read data from database and put inside configuration then it works automatically. search for database configuration provider and you will get implementation on how to read database and add configuration.

Comment: sorry may i know what do you mean "read data from database and put inside configuration " ?

Comment: Markus has covered in his answer almost everything what needs to be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IOptionsSnapshot` is a way to access the configuration settings of the application. Before, the settings are built using a set of configuration providers, e.g. providers that

- import information from files (appSettings.json)
- read environment variables
- read command line args
- (include user secrets in development)

Usually, a default set of providers is configured for an application, but you can extend this and add your own provider that accesses the information in the database.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/custom-configuration-provider) describes the necessary steps to create a custom provider. The example also shows how to get connection information to a database in your custom provider.

Comment: but, i wanna get it from database not from json file

Comment: If you want to get it from database, you need to write a custom configuration provider. Please have a look at the docs (see link), it describes how you can build a provider that reads settings from the database.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a Nuget package for this: [JsonRepositoryConfiguration](https://github.com/Shoeib-Yarmand/Json-repository-configuration). It also has a auto-refresh feature and works pretty much like configuration form JSON config files, only it expects the JSON config from your repository which can in turn bring the data from any internal/external storage including making a database call, API call etc.

All `IOptions<>`, `IOptionsMonitor<>`, `IOptionsSnapshot<>` are supported.
You can also mix different configuration provides (like this one and JSON config files) and use them together should you like to.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).